# Xamarin.IOS custom entry underline is longer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

[image]

What can I do with a user record so that its length matches the button?

*CustomEntryUnderlineRenderer.cs*

```
OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null)
                return;

            Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;

            CALayer line = new CALayer
            {
                Frame = new CGRect(0, Frame.Height, Frame.Width, 1f)
            };

            Control.Layer.AddSublayer(line);
        }
```

*Page.xaml*

```
<StackLayout Margin="20,0">
            <Label Text="The address of your server:" FontSize="Small" FontFamily="{StaticResource RalewayNormal}" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <local:CustomEntryUnderline x:Name="addressEntry" Margin="0,15,0,0" FontSize="Small" Text="http://192.168.0.217/PelicanMobile" Placeholder="Enter the server address" FontFamily="{StaticResource RalewayNormal}" TextColor="White" PlaceholderColor="White"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnAdressEnter" Text="Enter" BorderRadius="0" Clicked="OnButtonClicked_Enter" FontSize="Small" FontFamily="{StaticResource RalewayNormal}" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#E67E20"/>
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Set the `Width` of line equal the width of the button.

Comment: Are you using Xamarin.Forms? the problem is in your XAML Layout.

Comment: Apply width to local:CustomEntryUnderline to adjust width as per requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will can help with this question
https://xamgirl.com/image-entry-in-xamarin-forms/